# Best way to validate address with geocode?

Tags: coldfusion, geocode, street-address

In my project I have to use `geocode` to validate user input address fields. This includes Address, City, State, and Zip. When user entered value those information are sent to `geocode` server as `http` parameters. The return result is xml file content. I use ColdFusion 2018 as my back-end programming language. I'm able to navigate through the document and get to the section that contains data. Here is example of what I get back from `geocode`:

[image]

As you can see in the image above I will get the information with overall correctness of the address. My question is how this should be handled and presented to the user before I save data? Should I display the returned data back and tell them that address is 100% correct like in this case or maybe if address is not 100% show them the address as suggestion? I'm not sure which approach is the best way to go and I never used `geocode` before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only show the user something if they have to make a correction.

Comment: Why you could not use auto complete suggestion on address ? 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: @Kannan.P I would love to use that but there are some limitations in terms of security of the system that I'm working on.

Comment: Question is better suited for https://ux.stackexchange.com/. If the input does not match the corrected address, show the user and have him reconfirm. Otherwise silently accept his input and move on.

Comment: @Kannan.P, autocomplete in this situation has it's pros and cons.  If a mistake is made in the first text box, you could autocomplete incorrect information.  Plus, in the case of an American address, one probably needs the address, city, and state in order to get the zip code.  At this point there is not much benefit to the user.

Comment: You could review how other popular sites handle this.  Amazon.com has address correction for delivery addresses.